# Not capturing textbox values from a POST form that is using javascript to show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, forms, html, post, radio-button

I have a 3 radio buttons which show a certain div when clicked on and it's supposed to capture the values in the text boxes when the form is submitted, but it isn't capturing them

Here's the code, i'm using - i have commented the start and end marks of the part of that the showing and hiding of the divs, as someone requested to see the whole form code and it's rather long:

```
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="formrequest4" method="POST">
                 <table> 
                   <tr>
                        <td style="padding:15px">


                            <label >Who are you? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
                            <p style="font-size:8pt; color:black">What is your name?</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            if (isset($_SESSION['valid'])) {
                                echo "<input type='text' name='who' value='{$_SESSION['user']}' style='width:370px; height:30px;' readonly required/>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<input type='text' name='who' style='width:370px; height:30px;' required/>";
                            }
                    ?>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:15px">
                            <label >What is your email? <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
                            <p style="font-size:8pt; color:black">Your email won't be published anywhere, <br>it's just so we can contact you</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            if (isset($_SESSION['valid'])) {
                                echo "<input type='email' name='email' value='{$_SESSION['email']}' style='width:370px; height:30px;' readonly required/>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<input type='email' name='email' style='width:370px; height:30px;' required/>";
                            }
                    ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label >Interview type? </label>
                            <p style="font-size:8pt; color:black">ongoing star = multiple interviews<br>guest star = one-off interview</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='type'>
                                <option value='PLEASE SELECT ONE'>PLEASE SELECT ONE</option>
                                <option value='ongoing'>Ongoing star</option>
                                <option value='guest'>Guest star</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

<!--START OF THE CODE THAT HANDLES THE SHOWING AND HIDING OF THE DIVS-->
                    <tr><td>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function showhidediv( rad )
        {
            var rads = document.getElementsByName( rad.name );
            document.getElementById( 'one' ).style.display = ( rads[0].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.getElementById( 'two' ).style.display = ( rads[1].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.getElementById( 'three' ).style.display = ( rads[2].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
    </script>

                            <label>Please select one of these: <span class="form-required">*</span></label><br>
    <p style="color:black; margin-left:165px"><input name="pagetype" type="radio" value="1"  onclick="showhidediv(this);" checked="checked" /> Actor </p>
    <p style="color:black; margin-left:165px"><input name="pagetype" type="radio" value="2"  onclick="showhidediv(this);" /> Singer </p>
    <p style="color:black; margin-left:165px"><input name="pagetype" type="radio" value="3"  onclick="showhidediv(this);" /> Other  </p></td>

                        <td>
    <div id="one" class="CF" style="display:show;">
     <p style="font-size:8pt; color:black">What is your latest/most known role? &nbsp;&nbsp; <u>PLEASE NOTE:</u> IT MUST HAVE BEEN RELEASED<br></p>
                            <label style='font-weight:normal; margin-right: 18px'>Character Name: <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="character" style="width:270px; height: 30px" />

                            <br><br><label style='font-weight:normal'>Show/Movie Name: <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="role" style="width:270px; height: 30px;" /><br>

    </div>
    <div id="two" class="CF" style="display:none;">
     <p style="font-size:8pt; color:black">What is your newest/most known song? &nbsp;&nbsp; <u>PLEASE NOTE:</u> IT MUST BE AN ORIGINAL SONG<br></p>

                            <label style='font-weight:normal'>Song Name: <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="character" style="width:340px; height: 30px" />

                            <br><br><label style='font-weight:normal'>Band Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                            <input type="text" name="role" style="width:340px; height: 30px ;margin-left:1px;" /><br>
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="CF" style="display:none;">
                            <label style="font-weight:normal">What are you known for: <span class="form-required">*</span></label> <p style="font-size:8pt; display:inline; color:black">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Author / Model / Director / Athlete...</p>
                            <br><br><input type="text" name="character" style="width:370px; height: 30px" /><br>
                            </div> 
                        </td></tr>
<!--END OF THE CODE THAT HANDLES THE SHOWING AND HIDING OF THE DIVS-->

                    <tr><td style='padding-left:125px;'><label><br>Social Links:</label></td><td>
                            <p style="font-size:8pt; color:black"><br>Leave blank the ones you don't use/have<br><br></p></td></tr>

                    <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label style='font-weight:normal; padding-left:110px;'>Twitter</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="twitter" style="width:370px; height: 30px"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label style='font-weight:normal; padding-left:110px;'>Facebook</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="facebook" style="width:370px; height: 30px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label style='font-weight:normal; padding-left:110px;'>Youtube</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="youtube" style="width:370px; height: 30px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label style='font-weight:normal; padding-left:110px;'>Official site</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="official" style="width:370px; height: 30px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label style='font-weight:normal;padding-left:110px;'>IMDB</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="imdb" style="width:370px; height: 30px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

    <tr><td><label>&nbsp;</label></td><td><p style="font-size:8pt; color:black"><br></p></td></tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label >How did you find this site? </label>
                            <p style="font-size:8pt; color:black">Did someone refer you to this site?<br> Did you find it on Google, Twitter...?</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="referred" style="width:370px; height: 30px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:15px">
                            <label >Do you have anything to add?</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="extra-remarks" style="width:370px; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 20px"/></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <br>


                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left: 15px; vertical-align: top;">
                            <label >Human check <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">

                            <?php
                            require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                            $publickey = "6Lf7s94SAAAAADPKne_FeDykz5QcEQEyfoN8Q2uT "; // you got this from the signup page
                            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
                    ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr >
                        <td style="padding-top:15px" colspan=2><button type="submit" value="SUBMIT YOUR REQUEST" style="float:right; font-weight:bold; height:40px; background-color:#DE5635; cursor:pointer">SUBMIT YOUR REQUEST</button>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </form>
```

and this is a output values i'm getting from echo:

> who: test
>
> email: test@test.com
>
> character:
>
> role:

I typed in c under character field and r under role field, but they didn't get picked up

Comment: I don't see a `<form>`. Can you include it to make sure the elements in the form are actually, for sure, in the form?

Comment: `style="display:show;"` is not a valid value for `display`.

Comment: edit the code above to show the whole form, it's pretty long. interesting display:show appears to be working, what should it be?

Comment: Post a Jsfiddle, because that code it is not working. Also it lacks of form tag and a submit button

Comment: you don't need a jsfiddle account and at the very least, please, please fix you indentation

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the indentations that's the way netbeans set it out when I asked it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set unique names for

Actor -> character, Actor -> role;

Singer -> character, Singer ->role;

Maybe you are filling Actors character and role fields, but server receives Singer's fields(character and role)

Comment: good point, i'm trying that now, i'll let you know how it goes